# Is my Hiragana good?

Tags: hiragana, handwriting

[image]
This is probably asked a lot around here. I started learning Hiragana a few days ago and this is my progress so far Good? Bad? Give me your thoughts, I'm open to criticism.

Comment: Why would you not rotate & crop the image?

Comment: All the cool kids write ふ in 2 or even 1 stroke...

Comment: @istrasci how? I know how to Wright it with 3/4 strokes

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvUoakQf3I8

Comment: If you focus on proportions and practice writing in boxes, I'm sure it'll get better over time. Your kana are all recognizable though, and that's the most important thing. I wouldn't worry about writing ふ in a connected fashion right now; just be aware that there's some variation, particularly in ふ, さ, and き.  Right now you should try to write kana that look like 教科書体, a font used in Japanese textbooks to show children how to write properly: http://www.identifont.jp/show?1QA

Comment: Yes ,I am very aware of the variations in certain kana regarding the number of strokes. Thank you for the thoughts and the video( that handwriting is beautiful). I'll work on that font from now on.

Comment: See [Is it standard practice, or acceptable, to connect strokes in certain characters of hiragana?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6186/78).

Comment: Better 教科書体 specimens at: http://ch.nicovideo.jp/hnwpkids/blomaga/ar501918 (scroll halfway down). The DF series mentioned in @snailboat's comment is not developed in Japan, so not very ideal in kana shaping.

Comment: I once asked on meta whether there were any sites like lang-8 but for handwriting (answer: lang-8 is your best bet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all more or less legible, but some of the characters are very unbalanced. Personally I think your そ and と are pretty much fine, but the others are poorly shaped.

All Japanese characters fit into a square by design. Because of this, for hiragana as with katakana and kanji, squares are used to teach the proportions and ratios to students when they practice.

Take a look at this picture:

[image: な]

Here, a square is provided so that students can learn where to position the dots, loops, and cross within な. I think this is missing from your hiragana. Especially given that you were writing on squared paper, it's easy to see that your characters don't fit into squares, and that the proportions are non-optimal, especially with say, た, ほ, and は. Also, note where characters do and don't have flicks. な doesn't normally have a flick on the dot unless in calligraphy, and also with the こ shape in に the same is true.

Just take more time looking closely at how computers and people write them (computers are actually surprisingly good for Japanese character shapes compared to English). Closely copy where and how they are drawn, with careful attention to what type of strokes you're drawing. That's my main advice. That and practice squares.

Comment: thank you for your answear. Do you recommend pages like [this one](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_pSb79sM9CvY/TOLr5WAjxII/AAAAAAAAAIs/GKugL4O0GAw/s400/wired_kana_blank.jpg) too improve my Hiragana?

Comment: @thatdudethatslearningjapanese, those help a lot. There are some out there which have hiragana printed on them for tracing too at first, then blank ones after you've copied it 3 times or so. What do you think of these? http://japanese-lesson.com/characters/hiragana/hiragana_writing.html